# Check for match method for 2D array game

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a game that is called "Shapeshifter" and can't figure out how to check the 2D array game board to see if the shape that the user made with the cursor is actually the shape wanted. Any amount of code works, it just needs to actually work with the rest of the game.

Here is the code that I have done:

```
public static final int COLS = 7;
public static final int ROWS = 7;
public static int ZEE = 0;
public static int TEE = 1;
public static int ES = 2;
public static int OH = 3;
public static int JAY = 4;
public static int EL = 5;
public static int NUM_POLYOMINOS = 6;
public static int PIECE_SIZE = 4;
public static int UP = 8;
public static int LEFT = 4;
public static int DOWN = 2;
public static int RIGHT = 6;
public static int QUIT = 5;
public static int EMPTY = 0;
public static int POLY_PIECE = 1;
public static int PLAYER = 2;

private static int[][] getRandomPoly()
{
    int rint = new java.util.Random().nextInt(NUM_POLYOMINOS);
    if (rint == ZEE)
        return new int[][]{{1, 1, 0}, 
            {0, 1, 1}};
    else if (rint == TEE)
        return new int[][]{{0, 1, 0}, 
            {1, 1, 1}};
    else if (rint == ES)
        return new int[][]{{0, 1, 1}, 
            {1, 1, 0}};
    else if (rint == OH)
        return new int[][]{{1, 1}, 
            {1, 1}};
    else if (rint == JAY)
        return new int[][]{{1, 0, 0}, 
            {1, 1, 1}};
    else //if (rint == EL)
        return new int[][]{{0, 0, 1}, 
            {1, 1, 1}};
}

public void printCurrentPoly()
{
    if (currentPoly == null)
        return;
    System.out.println("Current polyomino:");
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < currentPoly.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < currentPoly[0].length; j++)
            if (currentPoly[i][j] == 0)
                System.out.print(" ");
            else
                System.out.print("#");
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}


public void initializeBoard()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++)
            board[i][j] = 0;
    currentRow = board.length / 2;
    currentCol = board[0].length / 2;
    board[currentRow][currentCol] = PLAYER;
    for (int i = 0; i < PIECE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        int rrow = new java.util.Random().nextInt(ROWS),
        rcol = new java.util.Random().nextInt(COLS);
        while ((rrow == 0 || rrow == board.length - 1) ||
        (rcol == 0 || rcol == board[0].length - 1) ||
        (rrow == board.length / 2 && rcol == board[0].length / 2) ||
        (board[rrow][rcol] == POLY_PIECE))
        {
            rrow = new java.util.Random().nextInt(ROWS);
            rcol = new java.util.Random().nextInt(COLS);
        }
        board[rrow][rcol] = POLY_PIECE;
    }
    currentPoly = getRandomPoly();
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    boolean done = false;
    ShapeShifter ss = new ShapeShifter();
    ss.initializeBoard();
    ss.printCurrentPoly();
    ss.printBoard();
    while (!done)
    {
        int move = ss.getMove();
        if (move == QUIT)
            done = true;
        else
        {
            ss.executeMove(move);
            if (ss.checkForMatch())
                done = true;
            System.out.println("\n");
            ss.printCurrentPoly();
            ss.printBoard();
        }
    }
    ss.printResult();
}

private int[][] board = new int[ROWS][COLS];
private int[][] currentPoly;
private int numMoves, currentRow, currentCol;
private boolean winner;
private Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

public void printBoard()
{
    System.out.println("+-------+");
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("|");
        for(int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++)
        {

            if(board[i][j] == POLY_PIECE)
                System.out.print("#");
            else if (board[i][j] == PLAYER)
                System.out.print("H");
            else
                System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("|");
    }
    System.out.println("+-------+");
}

public int getMove()
{
    System.out.println("Were do you want to move? (4=left, 2=down, 8=up, 6=right or 5=quit)");
    int move = stdin.nextInt();
    while(move != LEFT && move != RIGHT && move != UP && move != DOWN && move != QUIT)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid, only valid moves allowed are 4=left, 2=down, 8=up, 6=right or 5=quit");
        move = stdin.nextInt();
    }
    return move;
}

public void executeMove(int move)
{
    if(move == LEFT)
        moveLeft(move);
    if(move == RIGHT)
        moveRight(move);
    if(move == UP)
        moveUp(move);
    if(move == DOWN)
        moveDown(move);
    numMoves++;
}

private void moveLeft(int move)
{
    int currentRow = 0, currentCol = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++)
            if(board[i][j] == 2)
            {   currentRow = i;
                currentCol = j;
            }
    if(move == LEFT)
    {    
        if(currentCol != 0 && board[currentRow][currentCol - 1] != POLY_PIECE)
        {    
            board[currentRow][currentCol - 1] = PLAYER;
            board[currentRow][currentCol] = EMPTY;
        }
        if(currentCol != 0 && board[currentRow][currentCol - 1] == POLY_PIECE && board[currentRow][currentCol - 2] != POLY_PIECE)
        {
            board[currentRow][currentCol - 1] = PLAYER;
            board[currentRow][currentCol - 2] = POLY_PIECE;
            board[currentRow][currentCol] = EMPTY;
        }
    }
}

private void moveRight(int move)
{
    int currentRow = 0, currentCol = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++)
            if(board[i][j] == 2)
            {   currentRow = i;
                currentCol = j;
            }
    if(move == RIGHT)
    {    if (currentCol != 6 && board[currentRow][currentCol + 1] != POLY_PIECE)
        {    
            board[currentRow][currentCol + 1] = PLAYER;
            board[currentRow][currentCol] = EMPTY;
        }
        if(currentCol != 6 && board[currentRow][currentCol + 1] == POLY_PIECE && board[currentRow][currentCol + 2] != POLY_PIECE)
        {
            board[currentRow][currentCol + 1] = PLAYER;
            board[currentRow][currentCol + 2] = POLY_PIECE;
            board[currentRow][currentCol] = EMPTY;
        }
    }
}

private void moveUp(int move)
{
    int currentRow = 0, currentCol = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++)
            if(board[i][j] == 2)
            {   currentRow = i;
                currentCol = j;
            }
    if(move == UP)
    {
        if(currentRow != 0 && board[currentRow - 1][currentCol] != POLY_PIECE)
        {    
            board[currentRow - 1][currentCol] = PLAYER;
            board[currentRow][currentCol] = EMPTY;
        }
        if(currentRow != 0 && board[currentRow - 1][currentCol] == POLY_PIECE && board[currentRow - 2][currentCol] != POLY_PIECE)
        {
            board[currentRow - 1][currentCol] = PLAYER;
            board[currentRow - 2][currentCol] = POLY_PIECE;
            board[currentRow][currentCol] = EMPTY;
        }
    }
}

private void moveDown(int move)
{
    int currentRow = 0, currentCol = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++)
            if(board[i][j] == 2)
            {   currentRow = i;
                currentCol = j;
            }
    if(move == DOWN)
    {    if(currentRow != 6 && board[currentRow + 1][currentCol] != POLY_PIECE)
        {    
            board[currentRow + 1][currentCol] = PLAYER;
            board[currentRow][currentCol] = EMPTY;
        }
        if(currentRow != 6 && board[currentRow + 1][currentCol] == POLY_PIECE && board[currentRow + 2][currentCol] != POLY_PIECE)
        {
            board[currentRow + 1][currentCol] = PLAYER;
            board[currentRow + 2][currentCol] = POLY_PIECE;
            board[currentRow][currentCol] = EMPTY;
        }
    }
}


public void printResult()
{
    if(checkForMatch() == false)
        System.out.println("You did not win. You used " + numMoves + " moves to fail.");
    else
        System.out.println("You won!!n/" + "It took " + numMoves + " moves to complete.");
    }
}
```

Here is the final piece to the game that I am having trouble with:

```
    public boolean checkForMatch()
{

}
```

Comment: attempt to implement the method, come up with a specific question, and edit your request reflecting what exactly it is you need to know

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say whether the polyomino (not polynomial) can be in any orientation.  If so, I think you'll have to loop through the rotations and reflections and test each one.  For each orientation there are not many positions where it can line up with the board.  For each you need to check each spot and see if the player has filled them all in.

Since your polyominoes are defined in advance, for optimization you could also define constants for each one saying which ways it's symmetrical, so you can avoid redundant tests.  Not that extra tests would actually matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can "re-use" a lot of the code you already wrote for `printCurrentPoly` and `printBoard` to implement `checkForWinner`.

The idea is to go through all the cells of the board. For each cell check:  if the current poly would start at this cell are all `#` cells in the poly matched with the player char (`o` or `x`) on the board. If yes, the player is a winner. Otherwise go to the next cell.

Here the relevant code:

```
/**
 * Returns true when the current polyTicTacToc can be found at x,y of the 
 * board, with its cells filled for the given player.
 */
private boolean isPoly(int x, int y, char player) {
    if (currentPoly == null)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < currentPoly.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < currentPoly[0].length; j++) {
            char c = currentPoly[i][j];
            if (c == '#') {
                if (boardCellAt(x + i, y + j) != player) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return true;
}

private char boardCellAt(int i, int j) {
    if (i >= board.length || j >= board[0].length) {
        return ' ';
    }
    return board[i][j];
}

/**
 * Check the entire game board to see if the given player has     constructed
 * the polyomino.
 */
public boolean checkForWinner(char player)// Lab2
{
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
            if (isPoly(i, j, player)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

BTW: There is a bug in printBoard. The loop should look like this:

```
    for(int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++)
```

or you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Also in printBoard you should change the first print to `System.out.print("|");` otherwise it looks like there are extra cells left on the board.